# how many fields can be in a django model?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I see some issues in my database while updating my model in Django. it only shows 12 fields!

when I added one more field to it and then run `makemigrations` command, it does not show any changes.

I'm using MySQL database init. is there anything in the Django model like we can only define some fields or we can define as much as we need?

Comment: Don't know max no limit but definitely we can have a lot more field then 12. I guess makemigrations hasn't been done properly. Try python manage.py makemigrations yourappname. Then migrate

Comment: okay! was confused about it if I can have field of more than 12 or not! .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be a able to create as my fields as you want. I recommend deleting all files in your migrations folder, except `__int__.py` file and try `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` again.

If this doesn't work, also delete the db.sqlite3 file. This usually works for me!

Comment: yeah, I tried that! but it did not work for me! and yeah I'm using MySQL for db!

but it should solve this issue!